# RabbitMQ Docker Compose None of the specified endpoints were reachable

Tags: c#, .net, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I know this looks duplicated, but I checked all the others questions and none of them solved my problem.

**So, this is my docker-compose yml file:**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  #db:
   # image: postgres

  messageBroker:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    hostname: "messageBroker"
    healthcheck:
      test: rabbitmq-diagnostics -q ping
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 15s
      retries: 3
    networks:
      - services-network
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "admin"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "password"

  serviceDiscovery:
    image: steeltoeoss/eureka-server
    hostname: eureka-server
    networks:
      - services-network
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    
  order-api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}orderapi
    hostname: orderapi
    environment:
      - Eureka__Client__ServiceUrl=http://serviceDiscovery:8761/eureka/
      - Eureka__Client__ShouldRegisterWithEureka=true
      - Eureka__Client__ValidateCertificates=false
    networks:
      - services-network
    depends_on:
      - serviceDiscovery
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services/Order/Dockerfile
    links:
      - "serviceDiscovery"

  product-api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}productapi
    hostname: productapi
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - Eureka__Client__ServiceUrl=http://serviceDiscovery:8761/eureka/
      - Eureka__Client__ShouldRegisterWithEureka=true
      - Eureka__Client__ValidateCertificates=false
    networks:
      - services-network
    depends_on:
      messageBroker:
        condition: service_healthy
      serviceDiscovery:
        condition: service_started
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services/Products/Dockerfile
    links:
      - "serviceDiscovery"
      - "messageBroker"
        
        
        
networks:
  services-network:
```

**this is my config file which I connect to RabbitMq:**

```
using RabbitMQ.Client;

namespace MessageBroker;

public static class MessageBrokerConfig
{
    public static IModel ChannelConfig()
    {
        var channel = new ConnectionFactory { Uri = new Uri("amqp://admin:password@messageBroker:5672") }
            .CreateConnection()
            .CreateModel();
        return channel;
    } 
}
```

**but when I run docker-compose up I still got the error:**

```
product-api_1       | Unhandled exception. RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
product-api_1       |  ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Connection failed)
product-api_1       |  ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException: Connection failed
product-api_1       |  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused
```

And the product service can register inside the Service Discovery without a problem, and I followed almost the same steps.
And I know that the problem isn't the rabbitmq container taking time to be ready, because I can connect on my machine. And everytime the product service failed to launch, it restarts, but no matter how much time it takes, I still got this error. And the log of the messageBroker container shows it's healthy (and if wasn't, I would not be able to access through my machine ).
I don't have any other ideas, I'm on this problem 3 days alredy and I'm going crazy. I checked tutorials, followed the steps and nothig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved, guys! Well, the configuration was correct. However, whenever I created a new container, it didn't build. Therefore, even if I changed the code, it still had the image of the first version of the code, with the "localhost" as the hostname. So the only thing I did was delete the image of the service and Docker created a new one with the correct code.
I see this obviously as a temporary solution, since it has to build everytime it runs/a new container is created. But this is another subject and I think it won't be hard to implement. Maybe with the arg `--build` in docker compose is enough. But I will only give attention to this later.

Answer (score 1):

Your docker-compose file does not have the networking setup correctly. IMO you don't need the links. Here is a minimal docker-compose that worked for me. I removed the links and I removed the service discovery  which isn't in play here for connectivity between rabbitClient and the broker.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  #db:
   # image: postgres

  messageBroker:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    hostname: "messageBroker"
    healthcheck:
      test: rabbitmq-diagnostics -q ping
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 15s
      retries: 3
    networks:
      - services-network
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "admin"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "password"

  product-api:
    image: ${DOCKER-REGISTRY-}productapi
    hostname: productapi
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - Eureka__Client__ServiceUrl=http://serviceDiscovery:8761/eureka/
      - Eureka__Client__ShouldRegisterWithEureka=true
      - Eureka__Client__ValidateCertificates=false
    networks:
      - services-network
    depends_on:
      messageBroker:
        condition: service_healthy
    build:
      context: client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
        
networks:
  services-network:
```

Comment: You are partially right, i don't need the links, but I still got the same error. I tested if the ports on rabbitmq were accessible from another container by creating a container with ubuntu image and I did `telnet container-ip-address port` and it connected. So i'm very lost

Comment: Did you try with the simplified docker-compose I pasted. I tested on windows with docker desktop and after removing the links it works. Also give it a few seconds for broker to come up. So you will see the error but it will clear after a few seconds.

Comment: Yeah, the docker-compose file was correct. The image I had of my service was wrong, it was the old one with obsolet dll's. So the service was always trying to connect as localhost. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

On the docker-compose, in the network is missing something, put it like this:

```
networks:
    services-network:
        driver: bridge
```

Comment: Actually not needed. When you run docker compose, by default, all the networks it creates already is bridge type by default.

Comment: Ohh didn't know it has bridge as default -.-, since in all my docker-compose I have it setup like that to communication btw them hehe